# Smooth Scrolling Not available on your platform

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome, my Smooth Scrolling flag is "Not available on your platform" in
`chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling`

And indeed, smooth scrolling does not work. Links [such as these](https://codepen.io/entozoon/pen/dyQerQY) scroll instantly rather than animatedly as they should, with `window.scroll, scrollTo, scrollIntoView,..`

I'm running latest Chrome (115.0.5790.98) on an Intel Macbook Pro (latest Ventura 13.4.1)

It also fails to animate on a fresh install of Chrome Canary (117.0.5913.0)

[image]

Comment: My question is of course, how can I make it work? Because it doesn't. And my platform is mentioned in the question

Comment: https://codepen.io/entozoon/pen/dyQerQY scrolls smoothly for me on Chrome 115 on macOS?